# Using Selenium with iframe and body tag in order to insert html

Tags: python, selenium

I'm new to selenium. I'm trying to insert add text in the `INSERT HTML HERE` section. The code:

```
<iframe src="" frameborder="0" class="cke_wysiwyg_frame cke_reset" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" title="editor, postContent" aria-describedby="cke_93" tabindex="0" allowtransparency="true">
   #document
   <html dir="rtl" lang="he">
      <head>
         <title data-cke-title="editor, postContent">editor, postContent</title>
         <style data-cke-temp="1">html{cursor:text;*cursor:auto}
            img,input,textarea{cursor:default}
         </style>
         <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="[SOME_URL]/Blogs/ckeditor/contents.css?t=F969">
         <style data-cke-temp="1">.cke_editable{cursor:text}.cke_editable img,.cke_editable input,.cke_editable textarea{cursor:default}
            img.cke_flash{background-image: url([SOME_URL]/Blogs/ckeditor/plugins/flash/images/placeholder.png?t=F969);background-position: center center;background-repeat: no-repeat;border: 1px solid #a9a9a9;width: 80px;height: 80px;}
            .cke_editable form{border: 1px dotted #FF0000;padding: 2px;}
            img.cke_hidden{background-image: url([SOME_URL]/Blogs/ckeditor/plugins/forms/images/hiddenfield.gif?t=F969);background-position: center center;background-repeat: no-repeat;border: 1px solid #a9a9a9;width: 16px !important;height: 16px !important;}
            img.cke_iframe{background-image: url([SOME_URL]/Blogs/ckeditor/plugins/iframe/images/placeholder.png?t=F969);background-position: center center;background-repeat: no-repeat;border: 1px solid #a9a9a9;width: 80px;height: 80px;}
            .cke_contents_ltr a.cke_anchor,.cke_contents_ltr a.cke_anchor_empty,.cke_editable.cke_contents_ltr a[name],.cke_editable.cke_contents_ltr a[data-cke-saved-name]{background:url([SOME_URL]/Blogs/ckeditor/plugins/link/images/anchor.png?t=F969) no-repeat left center;border:1px dotted #00f;background-size:16px;padding-left:18px;cursor:auto;}.cke_contents_ltr img.cke_anchor{background:url([SOME_URL]/Blogs/ckeditor/plugins/link/images/anchor.png?t=F969) no-repeat left center;border:1px dotted #00f;background-size:16px;width:16px;min-height:15px;height:1.15em;vertical-align:text-bottom;}.cke_contents_rtl a.cke_anchor,.cke_contents_rtl a.cke_anchor_empty,.cke_editable.cke_contents_rtl a[name],.cke_editable.cke_contents_rtl a[data-cke-saved-name]{background:url([SOME_URL]/Blogs/ckeditor/plugins/link/images/anchor.png?t=F969) no-repeat right center;border:1px dotted #00f;background-size:16px;padding-right:18px;cursor:auto;}.cke_contents_rtl img.cke_anchor{background:url([SOME_URL]/Blogs/ckeditor/plugins/link/images/anchor.png?t=F969) no-repeat right center;border:1px dotted #00f;background-size:16px;width:16px;min-height:15px;height:1.15em;vertical-align:text-bottom;}
            div.cke_pagebreak{background:url([SOME_URL]/Blogs/ckeditor/plugins/pagebreak/images/pagebreak.gif?t=F969) no-repeat center center !important;clear:both !important;width:100% !important;border-top:#999 1px dotted !important;border-bottom:#999 1px dotted !important;padding:0 !important;height:7px !important;cursor:default !important;}
            .cke_show_blocks h6:not([contenteditable=false]):not(.cke_show_blocks_off),.cke_show_blocks h5:not([contenteditable=false]):not(.cke_show_blocks_off),.cke_show_blocks h4:not([contenteditable=false]):not(.cke_show_blocks_off),.cke_show_blocks h3:not([contenteditable=false]):not(.cke_show_blocks_off),.cke_show_blocks h2:not([contenteditable=false]):not(.cke_show_blocks_off),.cke_show_blocks h1:not([contenteditable=false]):not(.cke_show_blocks_off),.cke_show_blocks blockquote:not([contenteditable=false]):not(.cke_show_blocks_off),.cke_show_blocks address:not([contenteditable=false]):not(.cke_show_blocks_off),.cke_show_blocks pre:not([contenteditable=false]):not(.cke_show_blocks_off),.cke_show_blocks div:not([contenteditable=false]):not(.cke_show_blocks_off),.cke_show_blocks p:not([contenteditable=false]):not(.cke_show_blocks_off){background-repeat:no-repeat;border:1px dotted gray;padding-top:8px}.cke_show_blocks h6:not([contenteditable=false]):not(.cke_show_blocks_off){background-image:url([SOME_URL]/Blogs/ckeditor/plugins/showblocks/images/block_h6.png?t=F969)}.cke_show_blocks h5:not([contenteditable=false]):not(.cke_show_blocks_off){background-image:url([SOME_URL]/Blogs/ckeditor/plugins/showblocks/images/block_h5.png?t=F969)}.cke_show_blocks h4:not([contenteditable=false]):not(.cke_show_blocks_off){background-image:url([SOME_URL]/Blogs/ckeditor/plugins/showblocks/images/block_h4.png?t=F969)}.cke_show_blocks h3:not([contenteditable=false]):not(.cke_show_blocks_off){background-image:url([SOME_URL]/Blogs/ckeditor/plugins/showblocks/images/block_h3.png?t=F969)}.cke_show_blocks h2:not([contenteditable=false]):not(.cke_show_blocks_off){background-image:url([SOME_URL]/Blogs/ckeditor/plugins/showblocks/images/block_h2.png?t=F969)}.cke_show_blocks h1:not([contenteditable=false]):not(.cke_show_blocks_off){background-image:url([SOME_URL]/Blogs/ckeditor/plugins/showblocks/images/block_h1.png?t=F969)}.cke_show_blocks blockquote:not([contenteditable=false]):not(.cke_show_blocks_off){background-image:url([SOME_URL]/Blogs/ckeditor/plugins/showblocks/images/block_blockquote.png?t=F969)}.cke_show_blocks address:not([contenteditable=false]):not(.cke_show_blocks_off){background-image:url([SOME_URL]/Blogs/ckeditor/plugins/showblocks/images/block_address.png?t=F969)}.cke_show_blocks pre:not([contenteditable=false]):not(.cke_show_blocks_off){background-image:url([SOME_URL]/Blogs/ckeditor/plugins/showblocks/images/block_pre.png?t=F969)}.cke_show_blocks div:not([contenteditable=false]):not(.cke_show_blocks_off){background-image:url([SOME_URL]/Blogs/ckeditor/plugins/showblocks/images/block_div.png?t=F969)}.cke_show_blocks p:not([contenteditable=false]):not(.cke_show_blocks_off){background-image:url([SOME_URL]/Blogs/ckeditor/plugins/showblocks/images/block_p.png?t=F969)}.cke_show_blocks.cke_contents_ltr h6:not([contenteditable=false]):not(.cke_show_blocks_off),.cke_show_blocks.cke_contents_ltr h5:not([contenteditable=false]):not(.cke_show_blocks_off),.cke_show_blocks.cke_contents_ltr h4:not([contenteditable=false]):not(.cke_show_blocks_off),.cke_show_blocks.cke_contents_ltr h3:not([contenteditable=false]):not(.cke_show_blocks_off),.cke_show_blocks.cke_contents_ltr h2:not([contenteditable=false]):not(.cke_show_blocks_off),.cke_show_blocks.cke_contents_ltr h1:not([contenteditable=false]):not(.cke_show_blocks_off),.cke_show_blocks.cke_contents_ltr blockquote:not([contenteditable=false]):not(.cke_show_blocks_off),.cke_show_blocks.cke_contents_ltr address:not([contenteditable=false]):not(.cke_show_blocks_off),.cke_show_blocks.cke_contents_ltr pre:not([contenteditable=false]):not(.cke_show_blocks_off),.cke_show_blocks.cke_contents_ltr div:not([contenteditable=false]):not(.cke_show_blocks_off),.cke_show_blocks.cke_contents_ltr p:not([contenteditable=false]):not(.cke_show_blocks_off){background-position:top left;padding-left:8px}.cke_show_blocks.cke_contents_rtl h6:not([contenteditable=false]):not(.cke_show_blocks_off),.cke_show_blocks.cke_contents_rtl h5:not([contenteditable=false]):not(.cke_show_blocks_off),.cke_show_blocks.cke_contents_rtl h4:not([contenteditable=false]):not(.cke_show_blocks_off),.cke_show_blocks.cke_contents_rtl h3:not([contenteditable=false]):not(.cke_show_blocks_off),.cke_show_blocks.cke_contents_rtl h2:not([contenteditable=false]):not(.cke_show_blocks_off),.cke_show_blocks.cke_contents_rtl h1:not([contenteditable=false]):not(.cke_show_blocks_off),.cke_show_blocks.cke_contents_rtl blockquote:not([contenteditable=false]):not(.cke_show_blocks_off),.cke_show_blocks.cke_contents_rtl address:not([contenteditable=false]):not(.cke_show_blocks_off),.cke_show_blocks.cke_contents_rtl pre:not([contenteditable=false]):not(.cke_show_blocks_off),.cke_show_blocks.cke_contents_rtl div:not([contenteditable=false]):not(.cke_show_blocks_off),.cke_show_blocks.cke_contents_rtl p:not([contenteditable=false]):not(.cke_show_blocks_off){background-position:top right;padding-right:8px}
            .cke_show_borders  table.cke_show_border,.cke_show_borders  table.cke_show_border > tr > td, .cke_show_borders  table.cke_show_border > tr > th,.cke_show_borders  table.cke_show_border > tbody > tr > td, .cke_show_borders  table.cke_show_border > tbody > tr > th,.cke_show_borders  table.cke_show_border > thead > tr > td, .cke_show_borders  table.cke_show_border > thead > tr > th,.cke_show_borders  table.cke_show_border > tfoot > tr > td, .cke_show_borders  table.cke_show_border > tfoot > tr > th{border : #d3d3d3 1px dotted}
            .cke_upload_uploading img{opacity: 0.3}
            .cke_widget_wrapper{position:relative;outline:none}.cke_widget_inline{display:inline-block}.cke_widget_wrapper:hover>.cke_widget_element{outline:2px solid yellow;cursor:default}.cke_widget_wrapper:hover .cke_widget_editable{outline:2px solid yellow}.cke_widget_wrapper.cke_widget_focused>.cke_widget_element,.cke_widget_wrapper .cke_widget_editable.cke_widget_editable_focused{outline:2px solid #ace}.cke_widget_editable{cursor:text}.cke_widget_drag_handler_container{position:absolute;width:15px;height:0;left:-9999px;opacity:0.75;transition:height 0s 0.2s;line-height:0}.cke_widget_wrapper:hover>.cke_widget_drag_handler_container{height:15px;transition:none}.cke_widget_drag_handler_container:hover{opacity:1}img.cke_widget_drag_handler{cursor:move;width:15px;height:15px;display:inline-block}.cke_widget_mask{position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;display:block}.cke_editable.cke_widget_dragging, .cke_editable.cke_widget_dragging *{cursor:move !important}
         </style>
      </head>
      <body contenteditable="true" class="cke_editable cke_editable_themed cke_contents_rtl cke_show_borders" spellcheck="false">INSERT HTML HERE</body>
   </html>
</iframe>
```

I'm struggling to understand how to use selenium with iframe. I already saw quite a few previous topics but could not understand from them how to solve my specific problem. It looks like the html should be inserted into the `body` tag which is in the `iframe` tag. I want the iframe to render the HTML. I tried:

```
body = driver.find_element_by_class_name("cke_editable")
```

But got:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".cke_editable"}
```

How should I do it?

**EDIT**: I probably should have explained the issue better. I the text box looks as following:

[image]

If I use the text-box without clicking the `Source` button then if I insert HTML it will treat it as text. But if I switch to `Source` mode and insert HTML and then go back from the `Source` mode it will display the HTML. The code I showed above is when i'm not in source code. I was suggested by @0buz to do:

```
    iframe=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[@title='editor, postContent']")
    driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
    body=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//body[@contenteditable='true']")
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].innerText = 'INSERT HTML HERE'", body)
```

And it worked! But it inserted text and for HTML it does not work. When I switch to the `Source` mode I get:

```
<div id="cke_74_contents" class="cke_contents cke_reset" role="presentation" style="height: 350px;">
    <textarea dir="ltr" class="cke_source cke_reset cke_enable_context_menu cke_editable cke_editable_themed cke_contents_rtl" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; resize: none; outline: none; text-align: left; tab-size: 4;" tabindex="0" role="textbox" aria-label="editor, postContent" title="editor, postContent" aria-describedby="cke_165"></textarea>
    <span id="cke_165" class="cke_voice_label">Press</span>
</div>
```

But if I enter text when I in `Source` mode, it does not show my in the Chrome's source code where it's being changed. Only when I in the `non-source` mode it shows my that that text is in the body. My goal is to insert **HTML** and not text. Is there a way to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

First you would switch to the `iframe`:

```
iframe=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[@title='editor, postContent']")
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
```

You should now be able to interact with the element. One way to update it is:

```
body=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//body[@contenteditable='true']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].innerText = 'insert text here'", body)
```

*Edit:*

**Adding `html` node with `js` example:**

```
script = '''
var new_el = document.createElement('div');
var text_value = document.createTextNode("Text for new element.");
new_el.appendChild(text_value);

var body_tag=document.getElementsByClassName('cke_editable cke_editable_themed cke_contents_rtl cke_show_borders');
body_tag[0].appendChild(new_el);
'''
driver.execute_script(script)
```

**Or - injecting html structure as innerHTML** (the node structure below is obviously just an example for you to replace; it is added line by line to the variable called 'html'):

```
script = '''
var html = '<div id="div1">text</div>';
html += '<a href="javascript: void(0)" id="a1">bla</a>';
html += '<div id="dvi2"><div id="div3"></div></div>';
html += '>>>more html nodes etc<<<';

var body_tag=document.getElementsByClassName('cke_editable cke_editable_themed cke_contents_rtl cke_show_borders');
body_tag[0].innerHTML = html;
'''
driver.execute_script(script)
```

Comment: Thanks. For some reason I get `Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".cke_wysiwyg_frame cke_reset"}`. I give it time to load (a minute to make sure) and I also see that its was loaded and that this class exists. What's the problem?

Comment: What about `iframe=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[@title='editor, postContent']")`? Do you still get "no such element " error? If so, any chance you could share more html source i.e. above the `iframe` tag?

Comment: that actually worked. It's now complaining with the same error for your third line of code.

Comment: Ok, let's change that to `xpath` as well: `body=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//body[@contenteditable='true']")`. Let me know if it works and I'll update the answer.

Comment: that actually worked! but I need to insert HTML and not text. Can you please consider my edit?

Comment: Updated answer. Note this is JavaScript realm, rather than Python; plenty of training material available online for anything more complex, although I believe the example provided is a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium doesn't support multiple class name using `find_element_by_class_name('cke_wysiwyg_frame cke_reset')` instead use css selector.

I would suggest induce `WebDriverWait`() and `frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it`() and following css selector.

and induce `WebDriverWait`() and `visibility_of_element_located()` and following css selector.

```
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe.cke_wysiwyg_frame.cke_reset")))
element=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'body.cke_editable.cke_editable_themed.cke_contents_rtl.cke_show_borders')))
element.send_keys("test here")
```

You need to import following libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```